# nHibernate "No persister for" on updating lazy property

Tags: nhibernate, proxy, lazy-loading

I'm getting the

> "MappingExecption: No persister for ProjectNameImportTypeProxy"

on an entity, but **only when updating it**.

I mean, I create the entity without issues. If I reload it and save it again I get the exception, which means that mapping is actually correct..

I don't get this error if I remove the lazy="true" mapping option.

This is the mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="ProjectName"
                   namespace="Projects.ProjectName.Model">
    <class name="ProjectNameImportType" table="mid_ProjectNameImportTypes">
        <id name="ID" column="ID">
            <generator class="hilo"/>
        </id>

        <property name="Code" length="255" not-null="true" index="idx_ProjectNameImportType_Code"/>
        <property name="Name" length="255" not-null="true" />
        <property name="Description" length="2000" />
        <property name="FilesShare" length="2000" not-null="true" />
        <property name="ZippedAssemblies" lazy="true" type="BinaryBlob" not-null="true" />
        <property name="FileName" length="255" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is the class:

```
   /// <summary>
/// Represents a projectName import type
/// </summary>
[UniqueEntityKey("Code")]
public class ProjectNameImportType : ModelEntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set code
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set name
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set description
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(2000)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set files share
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(2000)]
    public virtual string FilesShare { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set zipped assemplies data
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public virtual byte[] ZippedAssemblies { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set filename
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public virtual string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the code where you update?

Answer (score 4):

The reason of this behavior is hidden in the combination of three concurrent settings/events:

- the class itself is mapped as `lazy`
- the property `ZippedAssemblies` (*byte[]*) is mapped as `lazy`
- the entity as an instance was Evicted from the NHibernate session (e.g. by explicit Evict(entity) or by keeping it in a web session between requests).

When all these events happen together, *NHibernate* cannot update such an entity. What we have (after Evicting) is not *standard* instance, because of support for a lazy load of a (most likely) large property `ZippedAssemblies`

There are some possible scenarios how to avid this, but only one I would suggest:

> Whenever you want to Update this entity, re-load it (Session.Get(ID))
>   and change its properties with new values. Keep entity in NHibernate
>   session all the time (no Evict() no Session.Close()).

And then you can update it while changing `ZippedAssemblies` or not. This will work and could help in above case.